# retrieve Android ARM processor version programmatically

Tags: android, arm, cpu, cpu-architecture, abi

Is there a way to retrieve the ARM processor version programmatically? I'm trying to send it to Google Analytics. I've been told it's in the /proc/cpuinfo folder but I'm unsure how to retrieve this information in code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/09/read-android-cpu-info.html:

```
private String ReadCPUinfo()
 {
  ProcessBuilder cmd;
  String result="";

  try{
   String[] args = {"/system/bin/cat", "/proc/cpuinfo"};
   cmd = new ProcessBuilder(args);

   Process process = cmd.start();
   InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
   byte[] re = new byte[1024];
   while(in.read(re) != -1){
    System.out.println(new String(re));
    result = result + new String(re);
   }
   in.close();
  } catch(IOException ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
  return result;
 }
```

You can just do `split` on each line in the result and look for the line that starts with `Processor`.

Comment: Why go to the trouble of launching cat in it's own process?  Is there some reason you cannot just open /proc/cpuinfo as a text file from java?

Comment: I'm with Chris I would rather retrieve the file as text than use cat.